# Allow a Postgres user to bypass RLS for all tables?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

Is there a way to allow a user to bypass RLS for all tables is Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html), it is possible for a user to be [assigned the `BYPASSRLS` attribute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html) by another superuser.  With this, a user can bypass RLS for all tables in Postgres.

And of course, superusers can bypass RLS be default.

Comment: `BYPASSRLS` sounds like exactly what I want. Thank you!